# ValueError: No engine for filetype: 'xlsk'

Tags: python, excel

```
from datetime import datetime
x="Hello, it is now %s." % datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
import csv
try:
    with open('output.csv', 'w+') as csvFile:
        writer=csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerow(x.encode('UTF-8'))
        print(x.encode('UTF-8'))
finally:
    csvFile.close()
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
data.to_excel('output.xlsk')
```

Is this office365 problem?
or my code

environment:windows10

Comment: there is not such format `xlsk`

Comment: Yeah you want `xlsx`, not `xlsk`

Comment: I did mistake..

Answer (score 38):

Your title answers the question. There is no such excel file format as '.xlsk'. Perhaps you meant

```
data.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

?

Answer (score 0):

simply try

```
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27982444)

Comment: I was getting same error and i converted this  --data.to_excel('output.xlsk')-- to this ---df.to_csv("output.csv")-- is got my desired output,

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@osprey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55736144/19418661), the file output for excel files are generally ***xlsx*.**

However,

**pandas** relies on a package called [**openpyxl**](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/)

> (an engine to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm/xltx/xltm files)

to write pandas dataframes to excel files. Make sure to install this before writing out your data.