# pandas dataframe to excel

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to save to an excel file from a panda dataframe. After some methods of scraping the data I end up having the final method, where I generate the data to an excel file.
The problem is that I want the sheet_name to be an input variable for each scrape I do.
But with the code below, I got the error:

*ValueError: No engine for filetype: ''*

```
def datacollection(self,filename):

    tbl= self.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/table").get_attribute('outerHTML')
    df=pd.read_html(tbl)
    print(df[0])
    print(type(df[0]))

    final=pd.DataFrame(df[0])

    final.to_excel(r'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PROJECTS\Python',sheet_name=f'{filename}')
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736096/valueerror-no-engine-for-filetype-xlsk

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is that you are asking it to write to a file called Python, without any file extension.

You could name it Python.xlsx for example.

Or, if Python was the directory name, then it should be Python/somefilename.xlsx

EDIT: Given that you were trying to name the file after filename, you are using the sheet_name parameter wrong, which names the sheet instead of the file. Ditch the sheet_name and change the last line to:

`final.to_excel(fr'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PROJECTS\Python\{filename}.xlsx')`

Comment: What im trying to do is to save the file in the route C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PROJECTS\Python   BUT save it in this route as the file name = variable called 'file name'

Comment: I see, then you are using the code wrong, the sheet _name parameter is for the name of the SHEET, not the file. You should do `final.to_excel(fr'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PROJECTS\Python\{filename}.xlsx')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a file extension for the excel file:

```py
    final.to_excel(r'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PROJECTS\Python.xlsx',sheet_name=f'{filename}')
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

If using f' the path access must be changed from \ to / as:

```
def datacollection(self,filename):

    tbl= self.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/table").get_attribute('outerHTML')
    df=pd.read_html(tbl)
    print(df[0])
    print(type(df[0]))

    final=pd.DataFrame(df[0])

    final.to_excel(f'C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/PROJECTS/Python/{filename}.xlsx')
```

Comment: You can use both f and r flags. See my edited answer for details! If it is helpful for you, do consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

This might solve the error !!

```
final.to_excel(f'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PROJECTS\Python\{filename}.xlsx')
```